# Writing dynamic query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have table called employee as below

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id        INTEGER, 
  manager   INTEGER, 
  name      TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY(manager) REFERENCES employee(id)
);
```

I want to get the employee list with their manager names.

Comment: Do a self join.

Comment: BTW, manager should be an integer id.

Comment: And the id column should be the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join

```
SELECT *
   FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee e1 ON e.manager = e1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have already discovered this, but for others...

```
    SELECT e.name as employee, m.name as manager
    FROM employee e LEFT JOIN employee  m ON e.manager = m.id
    ORDER BY e.name
```

Comment: Your answer was first and it has better table aliases and overall structure.